# Executing Javascript File On Click

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript code to draw lines on canvas.

```
var canvas,
context,
dragging = false,
dragStartLocation,
snapshot;


function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}

function takeSnapshot() {
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
 }


function drawLine(position) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
    context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
    context.stroke();
}

function dragStart(event) {
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
    var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
       restoreSnapshot();
       position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
       drawLine(position);
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapshot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    drawLine(position);
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 6;
    context.lineCap = 'round';

   canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
   canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
   }
```

How can i add a button to this so that when the button clicked the code get executed? How can i do this? An example is given below to clarify the thing

```
 <input type="BUTTON" value="Exit" onclick="execute the javascript file to draw line" >
```

Comment: have you searched it on google

Comment: This is exactly what you just wrote "as an example"

Comment: @El_Matella when the line button gets activate i cant use free drawing tool. how can i avoid that?

Comment: @Mahi when the line button gets activate i cant use free drawing tool. how can i avoid that?

Comment: wrap your whole code into function . then call it by inline button onclick

Comment: how can call this whole code to a single function?@Mahi

Comment: @Mahi r when i call another function how can i stop the execution of other functions?

Comment: @Meta_Data stop execution means don't call them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, I would use the "button" tag instead of "input" for better semantics. 
Second, give the button an "onclick" parameter and set it equal to your "init" function.

```
<button name="draw-line" onclick="init()"
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to include the js file in your html :

```
<script src='file.js'></script>
```

then, you can execute the init() function onclick :

```
<input type="BUTTON" value="Exit" onclick="init()" >
```

Comment: downvoted, really? for saying what has been accepted as an answer, only with more details? ok then...

Comment: why you always go with votes . it's OP priority . whatever he want